# Multiple KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have a problem with my iOS app crashing. It uses core data (one managed object context) and ARC but also has a separate SQLite database, which can be fairly large. I am getting crash reports for it with the error:     EXC_BAD_ACCESS and usually with the code: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

The problem is that every single crash happens in a different place (there are over 30) and that usually those places don't usually include any of my code in the call stack. I think, therefore that I am doing something fundamentally wrong which is causing these errors to occur.

I have tried turning on NSZombiesEnabled, but then I find that the errors don't occur. Also, I have tried turning on core data debugging (level 1), but I find the same there too. The errors occur across a range of devices and operating systems. The crash reports show between 3.0 to 148.0 mb or ram remaining. All of the crashes are on the main thread.

So my question comes in two parts:
1) I can't find any reference to there being a problem using a separate SQLLite database in a core data project. Is there any potential pitfalls to doing this and docs on how to avoid those pitfalls?

2) Does this patten of errors suggest anything in particular which I may be doing incorrectly?

I have added a single crash report on the off chance it reveals something which my question does not:

```
0
com.apple.main-thread Crashed
0   CoreFoundation  CFRetain + 19
1   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 690
2   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 690
3   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
4   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
5   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
6   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74
7   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
8   cleverme    
main.m line 14
main
```